# Multiple Email validation in a single input field separated by ;

Tags: regex

Currently i am writing a software where a user can input more than one email in a input field separated by: ";"

Now i have a regex that validates the email but sadly enough doesn't work when i have more Emails in the input field when using the separation.

Has anyone ever created such a regex or is there anyone that is able to help me?

Thanx in advance and looking forward for a response.

Here is my Regex:

```
 [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,4}+(\;|)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the pattern which matches the following emails inside a non-capturing group with a preceding `;` and make it to repeat zero or more times.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,4}+(?:;[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,4}+)*$
```

And one more thing is, you need to escape the dot.